# Jave EE java.lang.ClassNotFoundException web.xml

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

Im trying to run a JEE project on Tomcat9.

I don't understand why this error occurs when I go to `urlOfMyProject/connection`.

This error occurs even if the path of my class is good.

[image: ClassNotFoundException]

Thanks

Comment: I guess, that this class cannot be found in the war file. Is your project structure according to the Maven guides?

Comment: try re-deploying the project